# Kotlin Compose glance App widget LazyColumn

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-widget, glance-appwidget

I'm creating app widget and I want to achieve that only part of the widget is scrollable.

When I created

```
        Box(
            modifier = GlanceModifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(ImageProvider(R.drawable.bg_widget))
                .padding(vertical = 16.dp, horizontal = 8.dp)
        ) {
            LazyColumn {
                 items(items = itemList) { item ->
                      Text(item.text)
                 }
            }
        }
```

Lazy column is not scrollable, but there is indicator to scroll.

[image: app widget]

That red rectangle should be scrollable but it isn't.
Orange rectangles are composable Boxes.

When LazyColumn is not child scrolling works.

I don't want to be whole widget scrollable...

Comment: It should work. Maybe the issue is the box wrapping? Why do you need that box? You could move the modifiers into the LazyColumn itself. Please, consider reporting the issue to the issuetracker with a reproducible sample https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=1097239&template=1611667

Comment: Box is just for an example. I have more complex structure. But when LazyColumn have a parent scroll doesn't work.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/270885486 created an issue.